# sum of elements in a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation

I have came across this problem while preparing a part of college entrance exam.

$A$ and $B$ are $3\times3$ matrix satisfying 
$$A^{101}=B\ ,\ B=\begin{bmatrix} -1&-2&-2 \\
 1&2&1 \\-1 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
and $$B^2=I_3$$

The question requires me to compute the sum of all elements
of A, which I know is $-3$ but I can't prove it.

Oh, by the way it is
$$ x^TAx$$where$$x=[1\ 1\ 1]^T$$

Comment: Isn't it possible that $A=-I$, than $B = A^101 = -I$ and we still have $B^2 = I$ as required? But in this case sum of all elements of $A$ is not 3, but -3. And it's also quite easy to construct $A$ having sum of elements equal 1 and -1.

Comment: Perhaps they ask you about the sum of the diagonal elements? (Not $3$ even then, though)

Comment: $A$ is not uniquely defined, something is missing..

Comment: I am pretty sure I typed the question right. But in the question B is a specific matrix.

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: If we know $B$ in the new version of question and assume $A=B$ then $A^{101}=B^{101}=B^{100}B=B$ and sum of elements $A$   = $ -3$.

Comment: Are the entries of $A$ restricted to be rational numbers (or integers)?

Comment: Rational numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses the crucial information given in the comments that $A$ has *rational* entries.

Since $A^{202}=I$, the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^{202}-1=\Phi_{1}(x)\Phi_{2}(x)\Phi_{101}(x)\Phi_{202}(x)$. This is a complete factorization into irreducibles over $\mathbb Q$. This is the key point. Here, $\Phi_n$ is the $n$th [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

Since the minimal polynomial of $A$ has degree at most $3$, it must divide $\Phi_{1}(x)\Phi_{2}(x)=x^2-1$.

Therefore, $A^2=I$ and so $A=A^{101}=B$.

Comment: Sir, how you written $x^{202}-1=\Phi_{1}(x)\Phi_{2}(x)\Phi_{101}(x)\Phi_{202}(x)$.

Comment: Sir, I know cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. How you written that factorization? Please help.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi, $x^{n}-1=\prod _{d\mid n}\Phi _{d}(x)$.

Comment: Thank you! The degree of minimal polynomial is considered through Cayley-Hamiliton right?

Answer (score 3):

$A^{202}=I$
, then, for example, it can be a rotation about any axis $x,y,z$ by $\theta= 2πk/202,   k\in Z$, but sum of elements is then $1+2\cos\theta$  which     is not generally $3$.

Comment: The answer is for the older version of question, when $B$ was unspecified and sum was $3$.